# autocomplete from google api is behind my popup

Tags: google-places-api

I have this problem with the .pac-container from the google autocomplete api,

i have this popup which the input field for the autocomplete is inside of.

the connection to the API works fine, but the dropdown with autocomplete suggestions is behinde my input field and the popup.

mt code is as follows:

this is my input field

```
<div class="pac-container"><div class="form-group">
  <label for="from">From:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_from_Id" style="width:100%" placeholder="From is required" onkeydown = "if(event.keyCode == 13) createKMReg()"></div></div>
```

this is my css
`.pac-container { z-index: 20 !important; }`

i have tried looking for suggestions on the internet, but it doesnt fix my problems.

i hope you guys could help me :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your issue that the community can check and see what's wrong in your code. With that, you can increase your chances of getting helped.